# Как сравнить несколько дат между собой?(выведены они все в человеческом формате, пример внутри)

Tags: php

есть три переменные, которые содержат такие вот значения:

```
  $now=strtotime(date('d-m-Y H:i'));
  $startdate = 10-04-2016 09:00;
  $finishdate = 15-05-2016 09:00;
 $finishdate = strtotime($finishdate);
 $startdate  = strtotime($startdate);
```

Нужно написать, условие, которое проверяло бы, находится текущая дата между датой начала и датой завершения или нет. Написал следующим образом:

```
  if(($startdate<=$now) && ($now<=$finishdate)){
  echo 'Начат';
  }else{
  echo "Не начат";
  };
```

Но так не работает, точнее все время "не начат"

Comment: а [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php) использовать не пробовали?

Comment: @BOPOH, да даже не знал про нее, что она дает, все форматы к нужному виду приведет, который будет понятным для php?

Comment: @BOPOH попробовал, конвертируется только текущая дата, даты в текстовом формате конвертироваться не хотят.

Comment: так это надо в вопрос указывать, я, например, когда делаю `var_dump(strtotime('10-04-2016 09:00'));` получаю нормальный результат, который уже могу сверить с `time()`

Comment: это надо в вопросе указывать, я делаю то же самое, что и вы, но у меня все нормально отображается. Раз у вас что-то не так происходит, значит вы делаете что-то не так, поэтому надо в вопросе написать что именно вы делаете (и что не получается), чтобы не только я это видел, но и остальным не пришлось комментарии читать

Comment: @BOPOH исправил, вот так код сейчас выглядит, да даже просто в echo не выводит.

Comment: у вас видимо отключен показ ошибок. код должен выглядеть вот так https://eval.in/561161

Comment: Благодарю, оказалось что в переменные еще и html обертка попадала)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строку с датой и временем нужно переводить в Unix timestamp с помощью функции [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php). А потом уже сравнивать, например так:

```
$startdate = strtotime('10-04-2016 09:00');
$finishdate = strtotime('15-05-2016 09:00');

if (($startdate <= time()) && (time() <= $finishdate)) {
    echo 'Начат';
} else {
    echo 'Не начат';
};
```

Сравниваем с [time()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.time.php), т.к. [time()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.time.php) возвращает текущее время в формате Unix timestamp.